# Updating tabBarItem more than once (three20)

Tags: iphone, ios, three20, tabbar, uitabbaritem

I'm trying to update the tabBarItem more than once, but I can't get it to work.

I've used theese methods:

```
self.tabBarItem = [[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New title" image:image tag:0] autorelease];
```

and:

```
self.tabBarItem.title = @"New title";
self.tabBarItem.image = image;
```

And they work, but only once. So now I'm stuck.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for both the `title` and `image` properties notes:

> You should set this property before adding the item to a bar.

It is probably wise to heed this advice. If you want to change the properties, just create a new tab bar item with the new settings and assign it to `self.tabBarItem`.

Comment: Yes, that was my first guess, but it still doesn't update more than once. This is the code that i use: self.tabBarItem = [[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New title" image:image tag:0] autorelease];